# Spring boot actuator/info is empty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

i try get actuator/info but is empty.

this is my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

this is my properties:

```
       management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info
       management.info.env.enable=true

       info.app.name=My App
       info.app.description=First trial
       info.app.version=1.0.0
```

this is my get:
{}

İ can't find the problem here. What can i do solve this problem?

Comment: Have you included the dependency `spring-boot-starter-web`?  Starting with Spring Boot 2.0, we need to add this dependency to expose endpoints via HTTP.

Comment: yes..         '<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>'

Comment: i get response but its empty...